# Matching background texture with centered div

Tags: javascript, css, background

I have a document where I use a 40×40 pixel repeated background texture on the `body`.

Then I have a `div` with a set width and height and centered with `margin: 40px auto 0 auto;`

Now, the background image of this `div` (let's say it's 960×500, same as the element itself) has the same texture as the `body`. I cannot use a transparent png, because of a graphical effect I'm trying to achieve with this image.

However, for the effect to work, the background of the `div` needs to be seamless with the texture of the `body`. The user should not even be able to tell that there is a separate block element there; just an endless sea of the texture, with a detail in the middle of it all.

This becomes difficult as the `div` is centered, and as such, its horizontal distance from the left varies.

How can I make sure that the background texture on the `body` always matches the simulated texture in the `div` **to the pixel**, regardless of page width?

I'm not scared to use a JS solution if necessary, but obviously would prefer a pure CSS solution.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what is your objective, what are you trying to do, as well as a jsfiddle example with the code.

Comment: What you want is impossible. You either center the image, or you align  it with the texture. You can't do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to set the background image on the body element to start in the middle. So:

```
body {
    background: url(to/your/tile.png) 50% 0;
}
```

This means that no matter how the window is resized, you will have a predictable area within the repeating pattern.

You'll then have to tailor the containing div's background to make the tiling in the body.

Here is some code showing how this method would work: http://jsbin.com/olabos/2/edit. Note how resizing the window does not put the pattern out of sync. Hover over the middle of the preview to see where the wrapping div is.

NOTE: some caveats to this technique, depending on how the browser handles half a pixel, you will get a 1pixel difference in the background. I don't know of another technique that will solve your problem, so hopefully you can live with being 1px off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use a 40x40 tiled image as your body background, and a 960x500 image with the same background on top of it, use the following code:

```
body {
    background: url(repeat.png) top center repeat; /* 40x40 image goes here */
}

div {
    background: url(overlay.png); /* overlay image goes here, must be multiple of 40px wide, example is 960px wide x 500px tall */
    width: 960px; /* must be multiple of 40px wide */
}
```

You may need to edit this CSS snippet and you may have to do a bit of tweaking to your overlayed image to get the seams to line up but this should line them up nicely with eachother. I've used it on a few sites before and it works well.

If you have any questions or if I have overlooked a certain scenario, let me know and I can take another look at it. An example of your code would be useful.